# Is there a way to conditionally format one cell based the relationship between two columns of values?

Tags: excel, vba

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYIBf.png)
I'm setting up a sheet that compares metal specifications(for impurities) to customer specification requirements. Essentially I want to input values in one column and from there all of the customer which those values are good for will be formatted with green text.

By "good" I mean the inputted values must be less than or equal to customer specifications.

I have tried different approaches using the traditional conditional formatting functions but was unable to compare two entire columns, just two individual cells.

For example, in the second screenshot, values in the third column are 0 which is less than or equal to the values in all the other columns so the customer names (first row) will be conditionally formatted with green font.

Comment: Can you add another screenshot showing what the output should be? Or explain your current data more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an entire column if you remove the"$" from before the cell's row number (I believe it defaults to have the "$". For instance if your formula were like this:

```
$A$1>$B$1
```

then change it to be this:

```
$A1>$B1
```

Then copy that formula down in from the cell where you made that rule, and it should copy as far down the column as you would like.